# Parsing for Specific Text in HTML href

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[I'm trying to only get the links that contain the text '/Archive.aspx?ADID='. However, I always get all the links on the webpage instead. After I get the links I want, how would I navigate to each of those pages? Thanks in advance!][1]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

url = "https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?AMID=41"
key = '/Archive.aspx?ADID='

page = requests.get(url)    
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if 'Archive.aspx?ADID=' in page.text: 
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?AMID=41"
key = "Archive.aspx?ADID="

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if key in link.get("href", ""):
        print("https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/" + link.get("href"))
```

Prints:

```
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3581
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3570
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3564
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3559
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3556
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3554
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3552

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Andrej! It's perfect. So, do you happen to know how I could navigate to each of those pages and download all the PDFs that have the text/title "Public Comment" in the name?

Comment: @lsignori To not clutter the comment section I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I'll try to look at it.

Comment: Sounds good @DevOps. I can only post every 90 minutes though.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, welcome to StackOverflow! Next time you make a post, I'd suggest formatting it a bit differently. Try pasting the code in instead of hyperlinking your entire question to an image.

As for your question: it's a logic mistake.

```
page = requests.get(url)
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if 'Archive.aspx?ADID=' in link:
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Is the correct solution.
Your problem line was `if 'Archive.aspx?ADID=' in page.text`. This is because `for` every link you were grabbing, you were simply checking if the ENTIRE page (`page.text`) has that piece of text, causing all of them to go through.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice and warm welcome! That makes complete sense, but unfortunately, it doesn't give any output. Ideas?

Comment: No problem, it would be greatly appreciated if you could mark my answer as "correct" using the check mark if it was helpful!